# Should I use a dash or a comma here?

Tags: punctuation

I googled this and found nothing.

> This is silly, and silly literally.

Word editor tells me the comma use is wrong here, but I don't want to use a dash because I don't want to "overdash" in my writing. I think the comma is okay here. Am I correct?

Comment: Neither 'This is silly, and silly literally' is such an odd phrase everything about it deserves questioning, in which light dashes or commas don't seem important.

My suggestions would include 'This is silly, literally' and 'This is silly, and that(,) literally' and 'This is literally silly' but in 20 years of writing and editing, I never saw anyone suggest 'This is silly, and silly literally' might work.

Comment: Would “This is silly, literally silly.” make sense and/or convey the right meaning?

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you whether you want a comma or dash here. Both are grammatically correct, but both have a different rhythm.

With the comma, the second clause is appended to the first after only a brief pause. The argument remains open to be continued after the full stop. E.g.:

> "This is silly, and silly literally. We shouldn't accept it."

With a dash, there is a larger pause between the two clauses and the second clause ends the argument. E.g.:

> "This is silly – and silly literally."
> "But..."
> "I'm not discussing this any further."